# How to reference NodeJS.ProcessEnv in Nest.Js ConfigService

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have a `HttpClientService` class as shown below

```js
@Injectable()
export class HttpClientService {
  private readonly keyCloakClient: AxiosInstance;

  constructor(protected readonly config: ConfigService) {
    this.keyCloakClient = axios.create({
      baseURL: config.get('KC_URL'),
      timeout: 10_000,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    });
  }
}
```

I also have `.env.development` with this content

```sh
KC_URL=http://keycloack.local
KC_REALM=local
KC_CLIENT_ID=local-service
```

I'm using the library [gen-env-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gen-env-types) to generate type declaration from env variables.

After running the script my `env.d.ts` file has these content

```js
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv {
      KC_URL: string;
      KC_REALM: string;
      KC_CLIENT_ID: string;
    }
  }
}

export {};
```

Nest.js [ConfigModule](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration) parses the env file properly and it works as expected. I bumped an issue when I tried to use more strict types there.

As you can see from the example I use `config.get('KC_URL')` to get a specific value. However, if I make a mistake and pass a different string that doesn't exist as an env variable it wouldn't complain during the development unless a runtime error happens.

I followed the official [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#using-the-configservice) where I could do things like this

```js
interface Envs {
  KC_URL: string;
}
@Injectable()
export class HttpClientService {
  private readonly keyCloakClient: AxiosInstance;

  constructor(protected readonly config: ConfigService<Envs>) {
    this.keyCloakClient = axios.create({
      baseURL: config.get('KC_URL', {infer: true}),
      timeout: 10_000,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Although this example works just fine the problem lies here `ConfigService<Envs>`. Since I already have my env variable type declarations I'd like to reference them here instead of duplicating them.

I tried to reference it this way `ConfigService<NodeJS.ProcessEnv>` however couldn't get rid of the error. It works with the custom-defined type but not with `NodeJS.ProcessEnv`.

Any ideas or suggestions on how can I make it work without duplicating the types?

p.s.

This is a Typescript warning for that

[image: Typescript warning]

Comment: are you using the latest version of `@nestjs/config`?

Comment: Yes, I use `1.1.6`